# Any way to get tasks in batch from Step Function Activity

Tags: aws-step-functions

Currently, to get the tasks using poller from Step Function Activity, I am using following:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_GetActivityTask.html

But it gives the task one by one. Is there any way, I could take the tasks in batch?

Answer (score 0):

No, because each State Machine (SM) activity task will require response from worker so its like a two way communication. Each SM activity task will provide its own `taskToken` to an activity Worker and the Worker must include the `taskToken` in subsequent calls to `SendTaskHeartbeat`, `SendTaskSuccess` or `SendTaskFailure` in order to report the progress or completion of the task for each SM. Activity state should include `TimeoutSeconds` as suggested in the [best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-stuck-execution.html).

Comment: I didn't get the reasoning very clearly. I get it this is 2 way communication. But each result is uniquely identified by a task token I think. Isn't the task token unique for each task we get from Activity? If yes, can't we have an api which can give list of GetActivityResult? Your thoughts?

Comment: Sorry but I can't seem to get my head around what exactly would you expect from  GetActivityResult? If `GetActivityResult ` API would exist, would you expect to provide it a list of taskToken and expecting result received by the task?